# Postgresql - finding percentage

Tags: postgresql, percentage

| name | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Marketing | In Progress |
| Marketing | Completed |
| Marketing | Completed |
| Sales | Completed |
| Sales | Completed |
| Audit | In Progress |
| Audit | In Progress |
| Audit | In Progress |

For the above mentioned table, name "marketing" have 1 In progress(Status) and 2 Completed(Status)
So how to find % for this name column. If its "marketing" it has to be 66.66% because out of 3, 2 is completed and 1 is in progress.
For "sales" it has to be 100%. For "Audit" it has to be 0%
can someone help me out to find the query for postgresql

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is what you're trying to get:

```
with t as (select name,
count(*) as cnt_total,
sum(case when status = 'Completed' then 1 else 0 end) as sum_completed 
from marketing
group by name)
select 
t.name,
(sum_completed/cnt_total::float)*100 as completed_percentage
from t;
```

| name | completed_percentage |
| --- | --- |
| Marketing | 66.66666666666666 |
| Audit | 0 |
| Sales | 100 |

Here's [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d16e7368f6f38025521b696f65fdb487) also